# Is it possible to make a button that opens an existing form in a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to open a existing form using a button in a form?

What I mean with that is that I already have a form with a button on there, and if I click on that button it will *show up another form like a new tab* while I can still see my first form.

Would that be possible? If so, would I need to use classes or add a item to my project?

Comment: Do MDI forms work for you?

Comment: Any windows form will work for me, sir. @john

Comment: I think you misunderstand my comment. Please Google "mdi forms c#"